# How to import python code into flutter workspace

Tags: python, flutter

import code in .py to flutter workspace

```
import test.py  # not working 
import filelocation/test.py #also not working
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package for importing some other languages (python, java, ruby, golang, rust, etc.) to dart.

https://pub.dev/packages/starflut